# Merging k sorted lists using heapq module in python3

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, python-3.7, heapq

Problem:- merge k sorted lists.

I want to solve this problem using min heap which can be implemented with heapq module in python.
Below is the sample code of the function...

```
heapq.heappush(listwithoutNone,(node.val, node))
```

But the problem is that python interpreter is raising an error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'ListNode' and
> 'ListNode'
> heapq.heappush(listwithoutNone,(node.val, node))

So, I wanna use the node.val as a minheap node element, since I am passing a tuple, so what change should I do in the code so that minheap will heapify the heap with node.val.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you need debugging help with your code, edit the code in your question to be a [mre] with imports and some minimal sample data and anything else needed so anyone can paste the code into a file and _without adding anything_ run it to see the error you are getting.

Comment: Have you already executed this line `heapq.heapify(listwithoutNone)`  before pushing data to your heap?

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan nope, I am pushing the data first.

Comment: I think you should first `heapify` your list before pushing data to it or if you are using list then use `list.append()`. I can share the working solution from my leetcode if you need.

Comment: yes, please share your solution using heapq module.

Answer (score 2):

When tuples are compared, their first elements are compared, and then any ties are broken using their second elements, their elements, and so on. For example, `(2, "a") < (2, "b")` will evaluate to `True`.

Here, you are inserting `(node.val, node)` tuples into your heap, which attempts to compare them. If there is a tie on the node value, it moves on to the second element of the tuples - the nodes themselves. These are just `ListNode` instances. Python does not know how to compare two `ListNodes`, hence the error.

To enable comparisons between `ListNodes`, you need to implement the [rich comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).
A quick way to do it is to simply implement `ListNode.__lt__` and then use the [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) decorator:

```
import heapq
from functools import total_ordering


@total_ordering
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, value: float, label: str) -> None:
        self.value = value
        self.label = label

    def __lt__(self, other: 'ListNode'):
        return self.value <= other.value

    def __str__(self):
        return f"ListNode(label={self.label}, value={self.value})"



nodes = []
a =  ListNode(5, "A")
b = ListNode(3, "B")
c = ListNode(5, "C")
heapq.heappush(nodes, a)
heapq.heappush(nodes, b)
heapq.heappush(nodes, c)

while nodes:
    x = heapq.heappop(nodes)
    print(x)
```

Here we say that comparing two `ListNode` objects is the same as just comparing their values. With comparisons defined, you don't even need to insert tuples at all. You can just insert `ListNode` objects directly, and rely on the comparison methods.

Comment: Hey! Your explanation is great but the piece of code you have provided, is not working, The interpreter is still showing the same error.
Please tell me what should I do next?

Comment: Updated with a more complete example, using the `total_ordering` decorator to generate all 6 comparison methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about this: Leetcode **Merge k Sorted Lists**

I am sharing a working solution for you:

```
head = curr = ListNode(0)    # Creating a dummy node
    lst = []
    for l in lists:
        if l:
 # Here we need to first push val so that heap can know which is minimum and which is maximum. 
 # If we insert directly node then heap can't work proper way (in this case heapq.heappop doesn't return minimum node).    
            lst.append((l.val,l))    

    
    heapq.heapify(lst)
    while lst:
        val,node = heapq.heappop(lst)
        curr.next = node
        curr = curr.next
        node = node.next
        if node:
            heapq.heappush(lst,(node.val,node))
    return head.next
```

Comment: in this case, the space complexity would be O(nk) , isn't it?? Because you are appending the total element in the list (which is nk).

But it can be solved in O(k) space complexity...

Comment: Normally you should not consider your return data into space complexity. If you don't consider then space complexity O(K) i.e. K = no of lists.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-linked-lists-set-2-using-min-heap/

Check this out, I am talking about this solution.

your solution is different from the(geeksforgeeks) solution.

Answer (score 0):

To improve upon [Saurabh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67369047/), you can generate the final sorted list while iterating over the individual lists.

The idea is to first populate the heap with the first element of each sorted array tagged with the array the element came from, and whenever popping from the heap, add the next element of the array associated with the element just popped from the heap.

```py
def mergeKLists(self, lists: List[Optional[ListNode]]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    heap = []
    for i, l in enumerate(lists):
        if l is None:
            continue
        heapq.heappush(heap, (l.val,i))
        lists[i] = lists[i].next

    out = ListNode() # dummy
    cur = out
    while heap:
        val, i = heapq.heappop(heap)
        cur.next = ListNode(val)
        cur = cur.next
        if lists[i] is not None:
            heapq.heappush(heap, (lists[i].val, i))
            lists[i] = lists[i].next
    return out.next
```

This can also be modified so that the heap keeps track of the actual nodes so that no new nodes (besides the dummy head) are created:

```py
def mergeKLists(self, lists: List[Optional[ListNode]]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    heap = []
    for i, l in enumerate(lists):
        if l is None:
            continue
        heapq.heappush(heap, (l.val, i, l))
        lists[i] = lists[i].next

    out = ListNode() # dummy
    cur = out
    while heap:
        val, i, node = heapq.heappop(heap)
        cur.next = node
        cur = cur.next
        if lists[i] is not None:
            heapq.heappush(heap, (lists[i].val, i, lists[i]))
            lists[i] = lists[i].next
    return out.next
```

The heap will only ever contain a maximum `k` elements where `k` is the number of input lists. Thus, we address @Abhishek Jaiswal's concern that the space complexity should be `O(k)`.

Edit: add space complexity improvement analysis

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the **lt** function that ListNode offers.
Here is the code

```
def mergeKLists(self, lists: List[Optional[ListNode]]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    def my_lt(self, other):
        return self.val<other.val
    setattr(ListNode, "__lt__", my_lt)
    heap = []
    for l in lists:
        if l:
            heap.append((l.val, l))
    heapq.heapify(heap)
    head = ListNode(0)
    curr = head

    while heap:
        val, node = heapq.heappop(heap)
        curr.next = node
        curr = curr.next
        if node.next:
            heapq.heappush(heap, (node.next.val, node.next))
    
    return head.next
```