# How to alter the comparable method of tuple in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

Suppose two tuples are having 2 elements in both of them.

```
t1=(2,8)

t2=(5,6)
```

and suppose I want to compare both the tuple on the basis of the first element of both of them.
So, when we do `t1>t2`  then the output should be True (as t1[1]>t2[1]).

so I want to make a comparison between these two tuples on the basis of first element.

I know that I have to override the compare function of tuple. But I don't know how to do it.

So please tell me how can I do that?
(Suppose I want to compare the elements in ascending order...)

The reason I want to do that is :
[Merging k sorted lists using heapq module in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67358848/merging-k-sorted-lists-using-heapq-module-in-python3)

I am using `Python-3.8.5`

Comment: what do you mean by comparison greater than lower than what do you want to compare

Comment: What if the first element is equal between the tuples?

Comment: see the post again, now, it is mentioned...

Comment: What you want is already the built-in behavior... Did you try `t1 > t2`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes I tried but when I do t1>t2, only the first element is compared.

Comment: ....Which is exactly what you said you want.... The first element is compared, if it is equal, the second element will be compared

Comment: But what should I do if I want to compare the second element rather than comparing the first element?

Comment: That is not what you asked in your question and you already got mis-leaded answers. Please clarify your question with examples what is exactly the behavior you're looking for

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks for your suggestion,i have edited my question, if there is still something to be edited then please edit this question on your behalf... It would be a great help to me...

Comment: You can easily use my answer to make the comparison whatever you want it to be. The total_ordering generates all the other comparison operators using the __eq__ and __lt__ you provide. This is 'overriding' the compare function of the tuple in your own subclass of tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the first element of the tuple and compare.

```py
t1 = (1,2)
t2 = (5,4)
print(t1[0] > t2[0])
```

or if you want to filter or sort.

```py
sorted_tuples = sorted(list_of_tuples, key= lambda x: x[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the 'classy' way ;):

```
In [1]: from functools import total_ordering


In [3]: @total_ordering
   ...: class FirstItemComparisonTuple(tuple):
   ...:     def __eq__(self, other):
   ...:         return self[0] == other[0]
   ...:     def __lt__(self, other):
   ...:         return self[0] < other[0]
   ...: 


In [5]: a = FirstItemComparisonTuple((1, 2))

In [6]: a[0]
Out[6]: 1

In [7]: b = FirstItemComparisonTuple((2, 4))

In [8]: a < b
Out[8]: True
```